# Как реализовать календарь?

Tags: java, android, календарь

Товарищи, поделитесь опытом! Хочу написать свой календарь. Откуда можно получить данные: количество дней в месяце, сегодняшнюю дату, номер недели, данные о днях недели и т. д. Пригодятся любые мануалы, примеры и ссылки. Спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеку [joda-time][1]


  [1]: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Answer (score 4):

java.util.Calendar

Comment: @jMind, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 3):

[Вот](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) и SimpleDataFormat, например.
Сегодняшняя дата

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
String now = df.format(new Date());
```

[Тут тоже пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579632/android-date-year-month-day)